# what is the difference between adding a using statement or writing the namespace.classname approach

Tags: c#, namespaces

what is the difference between adding a using namespace; statement and the namespace.classname approach.
suppose if I want to use the XElement class I can add using System.Xml.Linq.XElement; statement to the top of the file and then use XElement class or I can use System.Xml.Linq.XElement whenever I need to use the XElement class.
which one is better/efficient?
which one is more of a programmers' approach?

Comment: using statement because it makes you write less. in some cases you have to do like namespace.classname ...for example two class with same name but in different namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are generally used to

- define the scope
- Distinguish between classes with same name(but in different namespaces).

In the resulting bytecode it doesn't matter whether you had "using" or "fully qualified name" in your code. The compiler always uses the full name.Hence no performance benefit.

However what must be noted that the "using" directive helps in eliminating redundancy in code for frequently used classes of a particular namespace.

For example remove

> using System;

from your code and start typing fully qualified names for all it classes.

However when two namespaces have same classes(one of which you want to use) you need to type in the fully qualified names to eliminate the Ambiguity in your code regarding which class you actually want to use.

Answer (score 2):

The using statement, usually declared at the top of the class file, is a way of initializing which namespaces to try to attribute the classes used within that class or module. From a compiler perspective, every class is resolved to its full namespace at compile (simplifying a bit here, I know) so there really is no performance benefit.

From a readability perspective, it is nicer to see code such as

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("Dir","FileName"));
```

rather than

```
System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine("Dir","FileName"));
```

The former option is easier to type and read. But neither is "better" or "more efficient"

Answer (score 2):

There is **no real difference** between the *using* statement or writing the *namespace.classname*. It is better for **readability** from one way, and it's for **repetitive use**. Let's say i am going to use the same class in my code like 4 times, why have the trouble of re-inserting the *namepsace.classname* everytime? Just put the using statement once and for all.

Comment: Doesn't the using statement add the definition of the class to your file that has the using statement?

Comment: Yep exactly, instead of writing the namespace.classname before your function, you just put it in the top of the file by the using statement. It's the same thing i swear. You may just use it before a function to remove ambiguity between 2 classnames, only use of writing the classname before every function.